# Jenkins getting stopped automatically in linux server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My jenkins server is getting stopped while the jenkins pipeline is running.

I don't know why its happening

Can anyone help me on this

Thanks in advance.

**Jenkins logs**

2022-02-28 11:36:16.019+0000 [id=78]    INFO    o.j.p.workflow.job.WorkflowRun#finish: pipeline #82 completed: SUCCESS
2022-02-28 12:33:52.148+0000 [id=230]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Periodic background build discarder
2022-02-28 12:33:52.171+0000 [id=230]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Periodic background build discarder. 14 ms
2022-02-28 13:04:29.255+0000 [id=278]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started telemetry collection
2022-02-28 13:04:30.277+0000 [id=278]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished telemetry collection. 1,015 ms
2022-02-28 13:33:52.148+0000 [id=332]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Periodic background build discarder
2022-02-28 13:33:52.158+0000 [id=332]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Periodic background build discarder. 5 ms
2022-02-28 14:33:52.148+0000 [id=425]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Periodic background build discarder
2022-02-28 14:33:52.158+0000 [id=425]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Periodic background build discarder. 5 ms
2022-02-28 15:33:52.148+0000 [id=526]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Periodic background build discarder
2022-02-28 15:33:52.156+0000 [id=526]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Periodic background build discarder. 4 ms
2022-02-28 16:33:52.149+0000 [id=631]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Periodic background build discarder
2022-02-28 16:33:52.161+0000 [id=631]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Periodic background build discarder. 7 ms
2022-02-28 16:36:45.550+0000 [id=646]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Fingerprint cleanup
2022-02-28 16:36:45.660+0000 [id=646]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Fingerprint cleanup. 106 ms
2022-02-28 17:17:51.445+0000 [id=704]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Workspace clean-up
2022-02-28 17:17:51.570+0000 [id=704]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Workspace clean-up. 121 ms
2022-02-28 17:33:52.149+0000 [id=732]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Periodic background build discarder
2022-02-28 17:33:52.157+0000 [id=732]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Periodic background build discarder. 4 ms
2022-02-28 18:33:52.149+0000 [id=827]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Periodic background build discarder
2022-02-28 18:33:52.157+0000 [id=827]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Periodic background build discarder. 5 ms
2022-02-28 19:33:52.148+0000 [id=914]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Periodic background build discarder
2022-02-28 19:33:52.162+0000 [id=914]   INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Periodic background build discarder. 5 ms
2022-02-28 20:33:52.149+0000 [id=1013]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Periodic background build discarder
2022-02-28 20:33:52.156+0000 [id=1013]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Periodic background build discarder. 4 ms
2022-02-28 21:33:52.149+0000 [id=1102]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Periodic background build discarder
2022-02-28 21:33:52.180+0000 [id=1102]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Periodic background build discarder. 28 ms
2022-02-28 22:33:52.149+0000 [id=1188]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Periodic background build discarder
2022-02-28 22:33:52.161+0000 [id=1188]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Periodic background build discarder. 9 ms
2022-02-28 23:33:52.148+0000 [id=1289]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Periodic background build discarder
2022-02-28 23:33:52.156+0000 [id=1289]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Periodic background build discarder. 5 ms
2022-03-01 00:33:52.148+0000 [id=1376]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Periodic background build discarder
2022-03-01 00:33:52.157+0000 [id=1376]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Periodic background build discarder. 5 ms
2022-03-01 01:33:52.148+0000 [id=1469]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Periodic background build discarder
2022-03-01 01:33:52.156+0000 [id=1469]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Periodic background build discarder. 6 ms
2022-03-01 02:33:52.148+0000 [id=1554]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Periodic background build discarder

Comment: You need to check the logs of your Jenkins instance. Without the logs, nobody can help you. Logs in linux machines are usually located in /var/log/jenkins. For other deployments, you need to check the environment and documentation.

Comment: hi @aLuViAn I added my Jenkins logs in question

Comment: Im working on the angular pipeline in logs it showed up only npm error build.
But my query is while the pipeline running the Jenkins URL is going unused state. But while I check in the Jenkins server its shows up it is in the active state. Once I restart the server I can able to use the Jenkins URL.